# Binding data to DataGrid through ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid

I am trying to bind an ArrayCollection result coming in from the server to my DataGrid
created dynamically in AS.

The result data is not getting Displayed in the Grid.

```
var dg:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
dg.width=650; 
dg.dataProvider=someArrayCollfromServer;
```

I am adding the dgColumn as runtime based on some data from a XML and it is the same as defined in below static format.

But if I use the same code and create the DataGrid as a Flex Component as below, it works fine.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dg" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{someArrayCollfromServer}">
<mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Value" headerText="Value"/>
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Code" headerText="Code" />
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

This works fine. Is there some functionality or implementation different as far as DataGrid is concerned in Flex and AS.

Any point of issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dg.dataProvider=someArrayCollfromServer;` just assigns the current value of the variable `someArrayCollfromServer` (which might be null if it hasn't been populated yet) to the `dataProvider`. To get data binding, replace that line with:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(dg, "dataProvider", this, "someArrayCollfromServer");
```

And make sure that `someArrayCollfromServer` is `[Bindable]`